# Wordpress: Button in navigation menu

Tags: css

Would you please help me style a text in navigation menu? I would like it to look like a button.

It has this code:

```
<li id="main-menu-item-2217" class="free_download btn btn-mini btn-primary menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">

.navbar .nav li.free_download.btn {
position: relative;
bottom: 10px;
padding: 2px;
line-height: 19px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar .nav li.free_download.btn a {
color: #FFF;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
padding: 3px 13px;
}
```

[it looks like this now..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZsMl.png)

[I want it to look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4ja7.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your CSS

Comment: And in addition to posting your CSS, you can include the images in your postin place of the links. As it is, this question is virtually impossible to answer.

Comment: Its there. Sorry, I forgot

Comment: I Copied this codes in Wordpress forum.. now it just needs style like in the picture

Comment: `free_download btn btn-mini btn-primary menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page` I wonder what those 7 different classes do ...

Comment: the result is in the picture how it looks now.